# Why $b: V \times \overline{W} \to \mathbb{C}$ is $G$-invariant?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I am reading the book [Representations of Compact Lie Groups](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540136781). On page 79, in the proof of Theorem 4.6, it is said that $b: V \times \overline{W} \to \mathbb{C}$ is $G$-invariant. We have
\begin{align}
b: V \times \overline{W} & \to \mathbb{C} \\
   (v, w) & \mapsto \int_G \overline{<g \alpha, v>}<g \beta, w>dg.
\end{align}
We need to show that 
\begin{align}
b(gv,gw) = b(v,w).
\end{align}
That is 
\begin{align}
\int_G \overline{<g \alpha, gv>}<g \beta, gw>dg = \int_G \overline{<g \alpha, v>}<g \beta, w>dg.
\end{align}
But I don't know how to prove the above identity. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is not what you need to show. Given 
$$b(v, w) = \int_G \overline{ \langle g\alpha , v\rangle } \langle g\beta, w\rangle dg$$
you want $\langle h v, hw\rangle = \langle v, w\rangle $ for all $h\in G$, which is 
$$\int_G \overline{ \langle g\alpha , hv\rangle } \langle g\beta, hw\rangle dg= \int_G \overline{ \langle g\alpha , v\rangle } \langle g\beta, w\rangle dg$$
Using $\langle g\alpha , hv\rangle = \langle h^{-1}g\alpha, v\rangle$ and similar for $hw$, together with the fact that $dg$ is left-invariant,
$$\begin{split} b(hv, hw) &= \int_G \overline{ \langle g\alpha , hv\rangle } \langle g\beta, hw\rangle dg \\
&= \int_G \overline{ \langle h^{-1}g\alpha , v\rangle } \langle h^{-1}g\beta, w\rangle dg \\
&= \int_G \overline{ \langle h^{-1} g\alpha , v\rangle } \langle h^{-1} g\beta, w\rangle d(h^{-1}g) \\
&=  \int_G \overline{ \langle g\alpha , v\rangle } \langle g\beta, w\rangle dg\\
&= b(v, w).
\end{split}$$